# document.addEventListener working on android but doesn't on browsers

Tags: javascript, cordova

im working on phonegap project. Before compile for android and ios i was executing on browsers (safari,firefox,chrome), if i use document.addEventListener that work on android but not on browser and ios. If i want execute code on browser and ios i must to put the method directly Initdb(); for example, i dont know why:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", initDB, false);
var db = "";
//initDB(); //añadido
function initDB() {
try {
    if(!window.openDatabase)
        alert('not supported');
    else{

        var shortName = 'Pictogramas';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'PhoneGap Pictogramas Database';
        var maxSize = 9999999999;   // en bytes
        db = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

Comment: I think firefox, chrome and safari feel flattered now, after you called them "devices" but please tell me: What do you think should happen in your browser? How should he fire the "DEVICE"readyEvent?

Comment: ok ok, but then why dont work on ios? if i wait deviceready that never work i must put initDB();

Answer (score 1):

`deviceready` is a function for Cordova applications only, so it was never meant to work on browsers. You can determine if it's an app (on the mobile device) or a browser and call your `initDB()` anyway. And it is a good practice to add the eventListeners in a ready/load event. So add an onLoad event to your body:

```
<body onload="init()"></body>
```

and your Javascript:

```
function init() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", initDB, false);
    } 
    else{
        initDB();
    }
}
```

PS: The `navigator.userAgent.match` condition can be removed before releasing the application, becaue it will be unnecessary once the need of debugging is gone.

Comment: For what do you need the userAgent? Just place a document.addEventListener into your JS like you did inside your if.

Comment: Because the deviceready will never be triggered in a web browser.

Comment: Thats correct, but you don't need to specify the userAgent.
document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);
is enough.

Comment: But that `if` condition would be required while the OP wants to debug the application on a web browser, right?

Comment: i understand, that work for browsers but deviceready continue doesn't working on IOS

Comment: It must work on iOS if it is working on Android. Did you add the onload event to body? Also, is there any `app.initialize()` added by default?

Comment: @PerLucas Did you follow the building instructions for iOS? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: "Because the deviceready will never be triggered in a web browser", what if hi runs the code on an iPad mobile safari instead of executing the code inside an app?

Comment: @jcesarmobile, the apps developed in Cordova are never meant to be used in a browser; browsers are opted mostly for testing UI and pure JS, where one doesn't need to build the application for every change made while developing.

Comment: I know, but my point is your user agent check doesn't make any sense, you can test it as a web on the mobile browser for more accurate results, and mobile safari has a web inspector. Your user agent should check if it's a webview or not

Comment: When I had a similar requirement, I had used these lines of code and it worked, hence I posted. And I am not sure how to check if it's a webview; will this require native code?

Answer (score 0):

try calling the function like this.

Comment the line two while executing on emulator.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", initDB, false); //line 1 
    initDB();                                                  //line 2
});
```